# cv2.imshow() does not work properly when the image is small

Tags: imshow, opencv, python

cv2.imshow() does not work properly when the image is small.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
im = np.ones((5, 10, 3)) * 255
im = im.astype(np.uint8)
im[:, 5:, :] = np.zeros((5, 5, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('1', im)
cv2.imshow('2', cv2.resize(im, dsize=(20, 20), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST))

touch_img = np.zeros((5, 256, 3))
for i in range(25):
    touch_img[:, i*10 + 6:(i+1)*10 + 6, :] = im
touch_img[:, :6, :] = im[:, 4:, :]

cv2.imshow('3', touch_img)
cv2.imshow('4', cv2.resize(touch_img, dsize=(512, 10), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST))

im = np.ones((1, 2, 3)) * 255
im = im.astype(np.uint8)
im[:, 1:, :] = np.zeros((1, 1, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('5', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

These code will create 5 windows to show the different images. 
However, I found the following problems of these images' show results.

1. window 1 does not show properly;
2. window 2 shows properly;
3. window 3 does not show properly, because the rightest of image has some unexpected white region.
4. window 4 works properly.
   [image: problem-img]

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is coming from the image being too small, add the following line before your cv2.imshow('window_name', image) lines:

cv2.namedWindow('window_name', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

Then you can resize it to whatever you want. Reference: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow

Answer (score 0):

you can read the doc and the result is to add this line:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
```

before the line:

```
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
```

and the wall lines is:

```
cv2.namedWindow("Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```